# C2397: Conversation from 'int' to 'bool' requires a narrowing conversation

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to create a Sudoku board, and have a pointer reflecting to it. I did this by making a 2D array out of a struct that contained the number on that area of the board, and a boolean on whether it was placed there by the program or the player, so that later they will be able to remove the number if they place it incorrectly.

When the grid is filled with 0's, the error doesn't occur, but as soon as a number is added, it flags up with error C2397.

My code at the moment is:

```
struct sudokuNumbers {
    int number;
    bool solid = true;
};

class SudokuBoard {
private:
    sudokuNumbers sudokuBoard1[9][9]
    {
        5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2,
        6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8,
        1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7,
        8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3,
        4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1,
        7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6,
        9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4,
        2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5,
        3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9,
    };
};
```

I just don't understand what the program is trying to convert, because if I hover my cursor over the array it comes up showing that every value in the board has the `int` value assigned to it and the `bool` value as true.

Comment: When you say you hover the cursor over the array, is that during debugging? If so, that must be an out-of-date build if you're getting a compiler error for this one.

Comment: It shows it before the program's ran at all. Or would that still classify as debugging?

Comment: Here is a shorter example to show what's going on: https://godbolt.org/z/xKocnToGc . The [aggregate initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)'s not smart enough to do what you want. It wants to initialize all of the members, so `number` is assigned 5,  `solid` is assigned 3.

Comment: Ahhh okay I get it. I was afraid that might be the problem, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Joshua_R, It would be news to me to have the intellisense show a well-structured view of data before even running the program. Are you sure it's not just showing the same text you used in the declaration?

Comment: I'll be honest, it was probably that. I was so confused why it was displayed the correct integers with the correct bool next to each other, but then flagging up an error for the same thing.

Comment: Two obvious options - which is better depends on your needs (and subjective opinion).  One option is to define a constructor for `sudukoNumbers` that accepts an `int` and initialises both members.  Another option is (whether you add the constructor or not) to define the array as `sudokuNumbers sudokuBoard1[9][9] = { {5, true}, {3, true}, ......,  {9, true} };` where the `.....` represents all the other elements in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is too simple to do what you need done. It wants to initialize EVERYTHING, including the `bool` member with the default initializer. The compiler gets upset when it sees a `bool` being initialized with 3. It will gleefully accept 0 (`false`) and 1 (`true`), explaining why the all zero version of your initializer was accepted.

The simple fix is to add a constructor to `sudokuNumbers` that only accepts the number.

```cpp
struct sudokuNumbers {
    int number;
    bool solid = true;
    sudokuNumbers(int num): number(num) {} // new constructor
};

class SudokuBoard {
private:
    sudokuNumbers sudokuBoard[9][9] // uses new constructor
    {
        5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2,
        6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8,
        1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7,
        8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3,
        4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1,
        7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6,
        9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4,
        2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5,
        3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9
    };
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I just looked into it after reading Nathans comment. I didn't realise structs could also have initializers, I appreciate everyones answers.

Comment: @Joshua_R Fun fact: the only difference you'll likely ever notice between a `struct` and a `class` (and these days I'm pretty sure it IS the only difference) is `struct`s default to `public` access and `class`es default to `private` access.Everything you can do with a `class`, you can do with a `struct`.

Comment: Interesting. I think I remember reading about that on the c++ website, but I didn't realise it was so few differences between the two.

Comment: In the C++ standard, a `struct` and a `class` are the **same thing**, with just the subtle difference that `struct` defaults to `public`, and `class` defaults to `private`.  Not sure if this is still the case, but the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (CL.EXE) mangles differently for `struct` and `class` — which it really shouldn't, but does (or did) — which matters for *forward declarations*.

Comment: @Eljay The MSVC compiler I'm using (it's the one for Visual Studio 2017) actually generates a compiler error if do this.  Also, [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8IZ2ypvf19asA93Z) rather impressed me.

Comment: @Elijay - The standard allows `public`, `protected` and `private` members to be handled differently (e.g. laid out differently, or names mangled differently).    It shouldn't matter for forward declarations though.   Nothing wrong with `struct X` or `class X` being used for forward declarations of the same type `X`.   When defining the class, however, all definitions must be the same (in terms of the set of tokens making it up) so one definition in a program of the form `struct X { <whatever>};` and another definition `class X {public: <whatever>};` causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct is an int followed by a bool, so when you initialize your array it should look like this:

```
struct sudokuNumbers {
int number;
bool solid = true;
};

class SudokuBoard {
private:
  sudokuNumbers sudokuBoard1[9][9]
  {
       5,0, 3,0, 4,0, 6,0, 7,0, 8,0, 9,0, 1,0, 2,0,
    6,0, 7,0, 2,0, 1,0, 9,0, 5,0, 3,0, 4,0, 8,0,
    1,0, 9,0, 8,0, 3,0, 4,0, 2,0, 5,0, 6,0, 7,0,
    8,0, 5,0, 9,0, 7,0, 6,0, 1,0, 4,0, 2,0, 3,0,
    4,0, 2,0, 6,0, 8,0, 5,0, 3,0, 7,0, 9,0, 1,0,
    7,0, 1,0, 3,0, 9,0, 2,0, 4,0, 8,0, 5,0, 6,0,
    9,0, 6,0, 1,0, 5,0, 3,0, 7,0, 2,0, 8,0, 4,0,
    2,0, 8,0, 7,0, 4,0, 1,0, 9,0, 6,0, 3,0, 5,0,
    3,0, 4,0, 5,0, 2,0, 8,0, 6,0, 1,0, 7,0, 9,0,
   
   };
};
```

Comment: `0` is `false`, not `true`.

Comment: So would adding 0 keep the bool as the default (true) or would it assign it to true, meaning I can get rid of the '= true;' in the struct?

Comment: You probably just want to add some constructors to `sudokuNumbers`.

Comment: 0 would set solid to false, you can also change the above example to use true or false, for example:  5,true, 3,true, 4,true .... etc instead of 0